# Is memory fragmentation possible when malloc and free functions are called in order?

Tags: c, memory-management, embedded, malloc, free

I am doing an embedded system app in C and I was wondering of the following.
If one uses malloc and free functions in order, do you still have to worry about memory fragmentation?

Example:
malloc(a)
malloc(b)
malloc(c)
free(c)
free(b)
free(a)

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Ask your memory-manager.  Your mileage may vary.

Comment: Depends on the scheme used by the malloc library you are compiling with. If that is really your usage, you could write one that would be perfect.

Comment: If it is a requirement that your memory allocator be fragmentation-free when given this pattern then **write a memory allocator that has that property**. Then you will know the answer to your question.

Comment: Any more than one thread and...

Answer (score 3):

It is almost certain that the memory allocator will perform free block aggregation, so that adjacent free blocks will be aggregated into a single block.  There is no guarantee of that, but that would be conventional if not required behaviour.

There is of course no guarantee that the blocks a, b and c in your example are adjacent, but either way, on deallocation of all three, the heap will be in the same state as it was *before* allocation, in that sense it actually makes no difference what the order of deallocation is.

It is only the intermediate state that will be fragmented.  For example if the blocks are adjacent as follows:

```
aaaaaaaaaaabbbbbbbbbbbbbbcccccccccccccc
```

and you deallocate b before a or c, you will have two non-adjacent free blocks until either a or c are deallocated.

```
aaaaaaaaaaa--------------cccccccccccccc
```

However it is academic since as I said there is no guarantee of allocation of adjacent blocks in the first instance.  If you want to be sure of the behaviour, you would allocate one large block (statically or from the heap using malloc) and then allocate from that using your own allocator with an implementation that meets your application requirements.

Answer (score 0):

In your case you should not see memory fragmentation occurring.  You can verify that it is not occurring by doing your malloc/free sequence several times, say 1000.  If malloc returns the same values for a, b, and c, then I think you can conclude that no fragmentation is occurring.